# Upperbound in the number of spanning trees of a r-regular Graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, trees, graph-laplacian

i was trying to proof this upper bound in the number of spanning trees $t(G)$ of an r-regular graph G (and discuss what happens with equality)

$t(G)$ $\leq$ $\frac{1}{n}$$(\frac{rn}{n-1})^{n-1}$

What i tought was to use the matrix-tree theorem. What we know is that

$t(G)$=$\frac{1}{n}$$\prod_{i=1}{\lambda_i}$ where $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of the laplacian matrix of the graph(that is defined as the diagonale degree matrix minus the adjacency matrix of the graph). Now i think to prove that the product of than eigenvalues is less that power to n-1 but i don't know how to continue, i have to use the fact that is r-regular i think. 
Plus i googled around to proof this and i have found this document:
https://cs.anu.edu.au/people/Brendan.McKay/papers/SpanningTrees1983.pdf
Where in theorem 1.1 gives you three reference that i am not able to find anywhere online. Except for this reference book "Algebraic graph theory by Gibbs" that is a little bit expensive for just one proof.
Any ieas?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) of the arithmetic-geometric mean which in your context states that $$ (\prod_{i=2}^n \lambda_i)^{n-1} \leq \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_i.$$

Now the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace of the respective matrix which in your case is twice the number of edges. For a $r$-regular graph that is $rn$ as needed.